# Java stack cloning and changing

Tags: java, stack

The problem I'm getting comes when cloning and changing a stack.
It doesn't matter if I do it with ArrayADT or LinkedADT. The original exercise statement says I must implement some code that is able to clone a given stack and in the original stack, the "oldElem" is susbstituted by the "newElem".

My original idea was to take and Aux Stack so I can simply copy & replace the elemtents of the original one (due to the inversion of order according to the Stack inversed order) and that one copy again into a second Stack and so I could get the original stack in the same order and with the elements changed.

This is the code that I've wrote:

```
    public <T> BoundedStackADT<T> cloneAndReplaceWith(
            BoundedStackADT<T> sourceStack, T oldElem, T newElem) { 
BoundedStackADT<T> pila = new BoundedStackADTArrayImpl<T>(sourceStack.size());
        BoundedStackADT<T> pilaAux = new BoundedStackADTArrayImpl<T>(sourceStack.size());
        T result = null;
        T result2 = null;
        for (int r=0; r<sourceStack.size();) //I'm pretty sure the problem is here {
                try {
                    result = sourceStack.pop();
                } catch (EmptyCollectionException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (result.equals(oldElem))
                    result = newElem;
                pilaAux.push(result);
                r++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceStack.size();) {
            try {
                result2 = pilaAux.pop();
                pila.push(result2);
                i++;
            } catch (EmptyCollectionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return pila;
    }

}
```

I know T result2 is not necessary.

My problem is that doing the JUnit tests the returned Stack (pila) which is supposed to be the sime size as the original stack (sourceStack) is never bigger than 2.

How could I solve it?
Big thanks to everybody.

Comment: What is a `BoundedStackADT`?

Comment: @ChuckB Seems [practice code for a book](http://books.google.nl/books?id=GEJ_Jp6mUpgC&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=Bounded+Stack+ADT&source=bl&ots=9uBpWmiCLR&sig=8mO5ZtO1tAKZBYxgwOxPaRjbJpk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=w_1aU9GiKoaK0AWm2IC4BQ&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=Bounded%20Stack%20ADT&f=false).

Comment: The error may as well be in the `push` method for all we know. Have you tried to debug your code? Except from some general weirdness (variable definition before they are used, extracting `i++` out of the `for` loop, exception handling - just printStackTrace() instead of converting to `RuntimeException`) I don't see much wrong.